# I hide commandCenter, how can I reopen them

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set `window.commandCenter: true`, but I accidentally hide `launch Command Center` `Go Back` `Go Forward`.

Now when I right-click the title bar, there is nothing about them.

It used to be like this
[old-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vImzX.png)

But now it's this, I cann't open that three
[now-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VitA1.png)

I try reset `window.commandCenter: true` but nothing happened

Comment: Are the Go Back and Go Forward arrows gone as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try resetting all menus with the command:

```
View: Reset All Menus
```

When I do that it successfully brings back the Command Center and Go Forward/Back buttons but it puts them off-center which a reload fixes.

If you have hidden any other buttons/icons in the UI those will be reset too of course.

Answer (score 2):

you need to go to below, if you are on Windows OS

`File -> Preferences -> Settings`, search for "command center" and select the CommandCenter option.

if you are on Mac OS,
`Code -> Preferences -> Settings`, search for "command center" and select the CommandCenter option

[image: screen shot attached]

Comment: I select the CommandCenter option, but this is't the problem. I used to have CommandCenter, but I have hidden the top three modules separately. The  CommandCenter is selected, but I can't see `launch Command Center` `Go Back` `Go Forward`.

Comment: @Jalen can you try to uninstall your existing VS code and installed the old version 1.69
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69