# How to get VSCode command center at the top of the Window back after right clicking on it and selecting "Launch Command Center"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've unchecked "Launch Command Center" by right clicking on the command center at the top bar of the vscode window and now it's disappeared, how do I get it back?

Comment: At this point, you have to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74550193/836330

Comment: @Mark Thanks it's fixed now. I wish I could have that top command center as only a button (to take much less space), so I was trying all options and then I tried this option and lost it altogether :p.